# May there be many 'happier' more?

Tags: sentence-construction

I created a collage of my daughter's birthdays cakes (several birthdays) where I wrote :

> *Happy birthdays my dear...  May there be many happier more*

But I feel like the last sentence is not grammatically correct, yet I can't find the correct way to say that.

Is the last sentence grammatically false?
If so, what is the right way to say

'*may there be many more happier birthdays'*

Without repeating the *happy birthdays* part ?

Answer (score 1):

The only grammatical fault with I can see with what you wrote is that you pluralised "birthdays". Aside from being uncommon to do so, if you were actually wishing that all future birthdays are happy it becomes a redundancy to then say "any many more". The other unusual thing about your statement is that you are wishing future ones be "*happier*", and that almost suggests that this current one isn't as happy as it could be. What I think you mean to say is that they will all be equally "happy".

> "Happy Birthday to You... And Many More"

Many people conclude the "Happy Birthday" song by singing "any many more".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday_to_You):

> After the song is sung, party guests sometimes add wishes like "and many more!" expressing the hope that the birthday person will enjoy a long life.

If I were to correct what you wrote, I would say:

> Happy birthday my dear... and may there be many more.

Comment: I pluralised birthdays on purpose since the collage included more than one birthday cake. To give a little context that may be relevant, my daughter won't be receiving this till older

Comment: Oh, I just re-read that I wrote birthday cakes, singular birthday. Editing.

Comment: Of course "Many happy returns (of the day)" is another way of congratulating someone on their birthday.